# Combine data from two columns into one, except if second is already occupied in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

Say I have two columns in a data frame, one of which is incomplete.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b':[5, '', 6, '']})

df
Out: 
      a   b
0     1   5
1     2   
2     3   6
3     4
```

is there a way to fill the empty values in column `b` with the corresponding values in column `a` whilst leaving the rest of column `b` intact? 
such that you obtain without iterating over the column?

```
df
Out: 
      a   b
0     1   5
1     2   2
2     3   6
3     4   4
```

I think you can use the apply method - but I am not sure. For reference the dataset I'm dealing with is quite large (appx 1GB) which is why iteration - my first attempt was not a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure, if the blanks are strings `''` or 'NaNs' in dataframe?

Comment: this one ?`df.loc[df.b=='','b']=df.a`

Answer (score 2):

If *blanks* are empty strings, you could

```
In [165]: df.loc[df['b'] == '', 'b'] = df['a']

In [166]: df
Out[166]:
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  2
2  3  6
3  4  4
```

**However**, if your blanks are `NaNs`, you could use `fillna`

```
In [176]: df
Out[176]:
   a    b
0  1  5.0
1  2  NaN
2  3  6.0
3  4  NaN

In [177]: df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df['a'])

In [178]: df
Out[178]:
   a    b
0  1  5.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  6.0
3  4  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use np.where to evaluate df.b, if it's not empty keep its value, otherwise use df.a instead.

```
df.b=np.where(df.b,df.b,df.a)

df
Out[33]: 
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  2
2  3  6
3  4  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.where` using a boolean version of `df.b` because `''` resolve to `False`

```
df.assign(b=df.b.where(df.b.astype(bool), df.a))

   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  2
2  3  6
3  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` and `ffill` with `axis=1`:

```
df.replace('',np.nan).ffill(axis=1).astype(df.a.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  2
2  3  6
3  4  4
```